# How to use custom fonts in Rails 6 with Webpack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-sprockets

For my newly started Rails 6 application I want to have a set of customs fonts. My setup looks like this:

```
# app/assets/stylesheets/my-font.sass

@font-face
  font-family: 'my-font'
  src: url('fonts/my-font.eot') format('embedded-opentype'), url('fonts/my-font.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/my-font.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/my-font.svg#my-font') format('svg')
  font-weight: 400
  font-style: normal
```

And then under `app/assets/stylesheets/fonts` I have all 4 files referenced in the sass file.

My `application.sass` has the following import: `@import 'my-font'`.

When I run `rails assets:precompile` it also puts all 4 files with suffixed version (e.g. `my-font-7384658374658237465837246587263458.eot`) in the `public` directory.

BUT, when I run the application the browser is looking for a file in the root directory called `my-font.eot`, which of course isn't there and 404s. This looks definitely like a configuration problem to me, but where I have no idea. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: To be clear, this is *not* using webpacker but using Sprockets.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you have the fonts inside `/assets/` then use the `asset-url` helper.

```
src: asset-url('fonts/my-font.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
     asset-url('fonts/my-font.woff') format('woff'),
     asset-url('fonts/my-font.ttf') format('truetype'),
     asset-url('fonts/my-font.svg#my-font') format('svg')
```

That way Sprockets will change "fonts/my-font.xxx" to the filename with the digest.

Personally I don't like to put fonts on the assets pipeline since they are probably not changing and only slows down your precompilation time, so I put them in public:

```
/public/fonts/my-font.eot
/public/fonts/my-font.woff
...ect...
```

And just use your original css code.

(This has nothing to do with webpack or webpacker)

Comment: Thank you so much. That fixed the problem!

Comment: It is true that precompiling font files that hardly ever change is probably over-engineering things, however Sprockets also creates gzipped versions of every asset, which allows serving compressed files if the browser supports it. You loose that speed boost by placing files in `public` instead of relying on assets precompilation. WOFF files are compressed by design, but TTF, OTF and EOT can be largish.

Comment: What is the webpacker solution?

Comment: hey @LuisFlores, I wrote an article about that last month, it includes the webpacker solution to use fonts https://www.ombulabs.com/blog/learning/webpacker/webpack-all-the-assets.html

Answer (score 17):

1. Add your fonts into `app/assets/fonts` folder.
2. Now you need to tell Sprockets to load fonts in the first place. To do that, just add

   `//= link_tree ../fonts` to `app/assets/config/manifest.js`

Side note: you may come across advice to update `initializers/assets.rb`, but that is outdated, and Sprockets 4 wants you to add directive to load fonts to `manifest.js`.

3. You need to define `font-face` for use in your application, and your intention was right, but you need to use `font-url` instead of `url` for it to work, so

`src: font-url('my-font.eot') format('embedded-opentype') ...`

And notice that you don't need to specify `fonts` directory, because `font-url` already implies it.

Bonus: you can use [this sass mixin](https://gist.github.com/jonathantneal/d0460e5c2d5d7f9bc5e6#file-_mixins-scss) that simplifies specifying alternative formats for your fonts.

Comment: omg thank you. One correction, move the fonts outside the stylesheets folder